# After getting the APK source code, how can I import it into Android Studio to build an Apk?

Tags: android, apk, apktool

I've followed the steps to decode an APK file and got all the source code (Java + xml). Now I want to import all that code into Android Studio to build an APK by making some modification to that APK. I'm not able to import the project into Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. When you decompile an APK, you've not getting the whole original source codes. You can't use it to rebuild a new project on Android Studio.

Comment: i used apktool +jd-gui+framework-res and all, using the cmd.. now will i get the original source code by following the above steps.if no, are there any other methods to get the original source code.

Comment: _are there any other methods to get the original source code_ Of course, not !